# How to keep add one in text file?(Java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to make a unique code for the user by adding one everytime the user had input the informations(hour,minute,second...etc). For example the first user will get 1000 after the input, second user 1002, third 1003...etc. Now, with these code, the first user and other users always get 1002. How do I correct it?

```
Integer hour = Integer.parseInt(hourField.getText());
Integer minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteField.getText());
Integer second = Integer.parseInt(secondField.getText());
Integer date = Integer.parseInt(dateField.getText());
Integer month = Integer.parseInt(monthField.getText());
Integer year = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
Integer code= new Integer(1000);
code=new Integer(code.intValue() + 1);


try{

    FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("database.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
    code ++;
    bw.write(hour+" "+minute+" "+second+" "+date+" "+month+" "+year+"      "+code+"\r\n");
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

}
```

Comment: code seems to be doing what its expected. I dont see any issues.

Comment: You can use a variable outside method that stores last code or you can read the value from a file

Comment: why to use file instead of database to count the users or whatsoever operation. Files may changed by anyone, DB has `auto_increment` feature use it.

Comment: All your Integer should be int

Answer (score 0):

> How do I correct it?

You have to read the file to find the last used code and start from that value:

- read the file and parse its content to find the last generated code, if the file is empty, use 1000.
- increment the code, this gives you current user code
- write the updated code to the file

Comment: I'm sorry can u give me an example how to read the file? I am a newbie sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another file , `code.txt` which contains last code (last code not all code) and retrive it by

```
try{
    InputStream in = new.FileInputStream(new File("code.txt"));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String code = "";
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)   {
        code += line;
    }
    int cd = Integer.parseInt((code));
    reader.close();
 }
```

Comment: Or if you want to use the same file , you can use `code = line`  then find last index of space and then use substribg to get the code